# "He" as the antecedent of a relative pronoun

Tags: antecedents

> **He** that is always shooting must sometimes hit. [[source](https://jp.elsaspeak.com/4169-2/)]

**Question:** Is **He** correct?

A Japanese teacher of English says that it is not normal to use "he" as the antecedent of a relative pronoun, but I suspect that "he" is possible when it refers to a generic person. Even if **He** is correct, "One" might be better because it is gender-neutral.

Comment: Shouldn't that be " He who....."  (not that)?

Comment: Many people are saying that your phrase sounds "very formal" also may be missing that "words of wisdom" *are* very formal and a rhetorically phrased to sound "old" and therefore authoritative. Here, evoking King James-era biblical vernacular adds (undue) depth and "truth" to the statement.  Consider how much less profound this similar-meaning phrase sounds: "Even a blind squirrel finds a nut." yet both speak to the virtue of  persistence and eventual reward.

Comment: It's "samurai speak".  It's "biblical" sounding or "olde-days" sounding.

Comment: Yes, it's who not that.

Comment: O rmaybe whom  :)

Comment: "If you're always shooting, you're going to hit occasionally."

Comment: @Fattie "He that ..." is fine. The relative pronoun that can't be used to refer to a person is "which", not "that".

Comment: Compare with "He who laughs last, laughs longest", "He who hesitates is lost", "He who pays the piper calls the tune" etc.

Comment: The only part of the adage that strikes me as being unidiomatic is the progressive construction, which sounds quite _informal_ and thereby clashes with the rather _formal_ nature of the sentence as a whole. I would say, “He that/who always shoots must sometimes hit”.

Answer (score 22):

That example sentence is fine. Compare to the instruction from the Bible in John 8:7, “He that is without sin among you, let him first cast a stone at her.”

But that biblical quote is from the King James translation, which is three hundred years old. To modern English speakers, your example would be more naturally expressed as *He **who** is always shooting must sometimes hit*. And the use of the masculine to mean anyone of any gender is far, far less a convention than it was even one century ago. So yes, ***One who** is always shooting…* might be better still.

But… *he who* does remain common in at least a few aphorisms. I have not yet encountered any reworking of *He who hesitates is lost*.

As @JamesK writes, your example is in a fairly formal style that would not be commonly used in everyday speech… unless, for example, it’s in an aphorism. That’s a context in which that kind of formal (old-fashioned) style can be appropriate because the style itself implicitly helps communicate that the utterance is indeed an aphorism.

Answer (score 18):

It is highly formal in style, and so not common in general speech.  If you were talking, or even if you were writing something you'd not normally say this.  Instead you'd use a general noun like "People who are always shooting...".  Or you could use a conditional "If someone is always shooting,..."

There are problems using "he" to mean "a general person" (since it seems to exclude "she").  So it is correct English, but I'd advise learners not to copy this example.

Comment: Another natural way in modern English is with the generic *you*: “If you’re always shooting, you must sometimes hit.”

Comment: It is clear that it is being used as a proverb, and in a proverb highly formal style is commonplace.

Comment: It was not clear before the edit.  As a proverb... well I've never heard it, so It can't be a very common proverb. I suspect a "made up" proverb.

Comment: That's true, James, but isn't the example supposed to some sort of proverb, not part of 'general speech'?

Comment: Yes, that's true.

Answer (score 8):

That sentence is correct, though that structure sounds either highly formal, dated, or intended to sound dated.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/he)'s definition of "he" itself includes a relative clause with "he" as the antecedent of a relative pronoun:

> **2 —>** used in a generic sense or when the gender of the person is unspecified
> *he that hath ears to hear, let him hear*

The example sentence is over 400 years old, and just about every other example that comes to mind is a similarly old adage.

The modern way to express this is "**One who...**"

Comment: I am fond of saying 'He that was born to be hanged shall ne'er be drowned' about people who seem to narrowly escape too many calamities.

Comment: I am not a native speaker, but “one who” still sounds quite formal to me, and I would expect “someone who” in normal speech.

Comment: @CarstenS "One who", being more formal, is more recognizable as a generic person.  "Someone who" will be recognized as generic in the correct context, but being less formal can be confused with a _specific_ someone - "Someone moved my cheese."

Comment: @Kirt 'One who' is not only 'formal' but decidedly old-fashioned and these days probably only used for a deliberate effect. _One who lives in a glass dwelling would be well advised to refrain from throwing stones_

Comment: @CarstenS It is rather formal, but it's modern, and that's all I wanted to achieve. I didn't see any reason to make it less formal.